# Cannot get column name in table

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

Here is my code:

```
     conn.Open();
     string sql = "select min(IMG_ID) from IMGDETAIL where PRO_ID = @id";
     cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", nailId));
     da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(dt);    
     if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
          id = int.Parse(row["IMG_ID"].ToString());                      
        }
      }
```

I try to get an id column and it shows an error that my table does not have a `IMG_ID` column, however I check it has already this column.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 1):

Try the below - MIN(...) does not give the column the same name as the content of the MIN.

`string sql = "select min(IMG_ID) AS IMG_ID from IMGDETAIL where PRO_ID = @id";`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an `IMG_ID` column, but an unnamed column that results from the `MIN(IMG_ID)`. Use `AS` to give it a name like

```
string sql = "select min(IMG_ID) AS IMG_ID from IMGDETAIL where PRO_ID = @id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your query to avoid this error because your query creates an unnamed column , it should be:

```
select min(IMG_ID) as IMG_ID  from IMGDETAIL where PRO_ID = @id
```

If you use this it will give the column a name of IMG_ID